# How to disable auto unwrapping region after i accept Resharper InteliSense autocomplite

Tags: c#, resharper

After i accept Resharper InteliSense autocomplite, all my wrapped regions become opened and caret return to first line of code in xaml and c# code. How to deal with it?

i didnt found in reshaper settings how to disable it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not enough details here to understand how to help in this case. Please attach screenshots that demonstrate the behavior or contact support via "(Extensions) | ReSharper | Help | Report a Bug or Submit Feedback".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just disabled ReSharper autocomplete in the settings:

[image: setting location]